# Setting OpenGL uniform value from shader storage buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In OpenGL, I have one compute shader which writes output values into a shader storage buffer on the device.
Then another shader (fragment shader) reads that value and uses it.
So this happens all on the device, without synchronizing with the host.

Is there way to instead have the fragment shader receive the values as a uniform, except that the content of the uniform is not set by the host with `glUniform()`, but it takes the value that is on the device-side shader storage buffer? In a way similar to how `glDrawIndirect()` can take parameters from a device-side buffer, instead of from the host, avoiding pipeline stalling.

This would allow simplifying a program where the fragment shader will receive the value either as a constant set by the host, or dynamically from a previous shader, depending on configuration.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use it as a read-only SSBO?

Comment: to avoid also using read-only SSBO in configurations where it is not needed, or having two versions of the shader because of this.
and in case uniforms may be faster (similar to `__constant` or `__grid_constant__` in OpenCL/CUDA)

Answer (score 1):

Uniforms can be aggregated into an interface block:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform InBlock {
    // ... your uniforms go here ...
} IN;
```

Then the compute-shader written buffer can be bound to that interface block binding point:

```
glBindBuffersBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, buffer_id);
```

In fact this is the preferred way of doing things in general, rather than setting each uniform one-by-one.